# How to customize a window to take a photo

Tags: xamarin, maui, .net-6.0

For an android phone.

In .net MAUI, I want to customize a window with a "Take Photo" button, once this button is clicked I want to take a photo.

I know in Xamarin, I can install package `Xam.Plugin.Media` and then call `Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync` method to take a photo but I don't know how to do it in MAUI. I don't know if I need to install any packages for MAUI.

I know in MAUI, I can use `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials` and call `MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync()` to take a photo, but this method calls the default Camera app of the mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either go and implement your own wrapper for a camera control which,  especially for Android, is not really a fun task.

So the other option is to look at the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit) which has a `CameraView`. At the time of writing we don't yet have our .NET MAUI package ready, but we're working hard on it and should have the first previews this month.

Comment: Is the CameraView up and running, did the preview happen already or is this still work in progress?

Comment: There is a preview for .NET MAUI now, but I don't think it includes CamerView yet